# What are Christian arguments against the use of anesthesia?

Tags: biblical-basis, healthcare

I understand that the practice of using chloroform as an anesthesia was forbidden by Protestant Christians early in the history of its discovery. That is until Queen Victoria used chloroform during the delivery of her son.

What were the early arguments against the use anesthesia, what biblical references were used?

Comment: It certainly wasn't forbidden by/to all Protestants & the lapse in time between its first use clinically in 1847 and being used in Queen Victoria's deliveries in the 1850s is hardly long enough for this have been an issue on the radar of the major Protestant denominations   - what is the source of your understanding on this matter?

Comment: A quick search found http://typeaparent.com/painful-birth-is-the-curse-of-eve.html which says, "Anesthesia was withheld from laboring women until the mid-nineteenth century so as not to interfere with God’s “punishment.” Queen Victoria in each of her births was refused any pain relief!". Perhaps Queen Victoria had some of her children without anesthesia, but not all? I have certainly heard the claim that pain relief during childbirth was initially resisted. Apparently resistance was short-lived. New things are often resisted and silly arguments given.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. For some tips on improving your question to make it more solid and less subject to skepticism and speculation here, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Also helpful: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was no 'forbidding' from any official Protestant denominations. What opposition there was, centred on its use in Obstetrics and came primarily from within the medical community.  According to the abstract of the article [Early Opposition to Obstetric Anaesthesia](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7004261)<sup>1</sup>:

> Some of the arguments used to oppose the introduction of inhalation anaesthesia - especially in obstetrics - are considered. These arguments were mainly based upon a desire to retain the sensation of pain, either as a factor necessary for survival or as a diagnostic aid: moral arguments were also adduced but **religious opposition is no more than a myth of historiography**. The opposition to anaesthesia lasted for less than 15 years and is seen as essentially a reflection of contemporary views on the role of pain. [*emphasis added*]

This assertion is justified within the article itself as follows:

> *Religious objections*
>
> In 
>   addition 
>   to 
>   medical 
>   and 
>   moral  arguments 
>   it 
>   has  often 
>   been  alleged 
>   that 
>   opposition 
>   to 
>   anaesthesia 
>   was 
>   raised 
>   upon 
>   religious 
>   grounds. 
>   However, despite widespread references 
>   by 
>   20th 
>   century 
>   commentators 
>   to 
>   religious 
>   attacks 
>   upon 
>   anaesthesia, 
>   especially 
>   in 
>   obstetrics, 
>   evidence 
>   of 
>   any  such 
>   attack 
>   in 
>   contemporary 
>   writings 
>   is 
>   singularly sparse.
>
> In  December 
>   1847 
>   Professor 
>   James  Young 
>   Simpson published 
>   a 
>   pamphlet entitled 
>   *Answer 
>   to 
>   the 
>   Religious 
>   Objections 
>   Advanced 
>   Against   the 
>   Employment   of  Anaesthetic 
>   Agents 
>   in 
>   Midwifery 
>   and 
>   Surgery*<sup>33</sup> 
>   and 
>   it 
>   is 
>   this 
>   which 
>   appears 
>   to 
>   have 
>   caught 
>   the 
>   attention - and 
>   imagination - of 
>   subsequent 
>   commentators. 
>   In 
>   this 
>   pamphlet Simpson 
>   considered 
>   the 
>   assertion 
>   that  the 
>   use 
>   of 
>   obstetric 
>   anaesthesia 
>   was 
>   a 
>   breach 
>   of 
>   the 
>   ‘primeval curse’ 
>   enunciated  in  Genesis 
>   3, 
>   vl6 - "in 
>   sorrow 
>   thou 
>   shalt bring 
>   forth 
>   children" - and 
>   with 
>   a 
>   clever 
>   use 
>   of 
>   logic 
>   and 
>   philosophy  sought 
>   to 
>   establish 
>   that 
>   the 
>   use 
>   of 
>   anaesthesia 
>   during 
>   childbirth  did 
>   not 
>   actually breach Holy writ.
>
> In 
>   fact, 
>   as  a 
>   recent  exhaustive  study 
>   of 
>   the 
>   contemporary 
>   medical, theological 
>   and 
>   lay 
>   literature  has 
>   revealed, 
>   up 
>   until 
>   that  date 
>   no  such 
>   assertions  had 
>   been 
>   publicly 
>   made, 
>   nor  is  there 
>   any 
>   evidence of 
>   such 
>   views 
>   being 
>   held 
>   privately 
>   by 
>   any 
>   more than a 
>   small 
>   handful 
>   of 
>    individuals.<sup>34</sup>
>   It 
>   has 
>   also 
>   become 
>   clear 
>   that 
>   all  subsequent  comments 
>   about 
>   the  religious propriety  of 
>   obstetric 
>   anaesthesia arose 
>   as 
>   a 
>   result 
>   of 
>   the publication 
>   of 
>   Simpson’s 
>   pamphlet, 
>   and 
>   generally   referred 
>   directly 
>   to 
>   it. 
>   Indeed, Simpson 
>   himself 
>   wrote only 
>   7 months later 
>   that 
>   "Here, 
>   in 
>   Edinburgh, 
>   I 
>   never 
>   now 
>   meet 
>   with any objections 
>   on 
>   this 
>   point,  for 
>   the 
>   religious, 
>   like 
>   the other forms 
>   of opposition to 
>   chloroform, 
>   have 
>   ceased 
>   among 
>   us".<sup>35</sup>
>
> It 
>   may also 
>   be 
>   noted 
>   that 
>   the 
>   only two contemporary theologians 
>   of 
>   note 
>   who 
>   were 
>   consulted 
>   on 
>   the 
>   issue 
>   did  not  consider 
>   there 
>   was 
>   any 
>   ground  for 
>   religious  objections 
>   to 
>   anaesthesia. 
>   Thomas 
>   Chalmers 
>   (1780-1847), 
>   possibly 
>   the 
>   greatest 
>   of 
>   19th  century   Scottish  churchmen, 
>   regarded 
>   the 
>   issue 
>   as 
>   one 
>   for 
>   "small 
>   theologians" 
>   who, 
>   if 
>   they entertained  such  objections,  would 
>   thus 
>   be 
>   taking 
>   "an 
>   improper 
>   view 
>   of 
>   the 
>   subject".<sup>33</sup>
>   George 
>   Rapall  Noyes 
>   (1798-1868), 
>   Professor 
>   of 
>   Hebrew 
>   and 
>   Oriental 
>   languages 
>   and 
>   Lecturer 
>   in 
>   Bibilical 
>   literature   and 
>   theology 
>   at 
>   Harvard 
>   Divinity  School, 
>   has 
>   been  described 
>   in 
>   the 
>   Dictionary 
>   of 
>   American  Biography 
>   as 
>   "one  of 
>   the 
>   ablest 
>   Biblical 
>   scholars 
>   of 
>   his 
>   day". 
>   His 
>   view, 
>   expressed in 
>   1848, 
>   was 
>   that 
>   "God 
>   could 
>   not 
>   have 
>   intended, 
>   by 
>   any  thing   in 
>   the 
>   Scriptures, 
>   to 
>   oppose 
>   the 
>   development 
>   of 
>   any 
>   of 
>   the 
>   laws  of 
>   nature; 
>   which 
>   are 
>   his 
>   own  laws. 
>   The 
>   application 
>   of 
>   the 
>   agents 
>   of 
>   nature, 
>   by 
>   human 
>   ingenuity, 
>   to 
>   the 
>   relief 
>   of 
>   pain, 
>   is 
>   also 
>   the 
>   use 
>   of 
>   God-given 
>   means 
>   by 
>   God-given powers. 
>   How, 
>   then, can 
>   such 
>   a 
>   course 
>   be 
>   irreconcilable with any 
>   intimations 
>   of 
>   the 
>   divine 
>   will 
>   whatever?".<sup>36</sup>
>
> It 
>   is 
>   almost  certain 
>   that 
>   Simpson’s pamphlet 
>   *Answer 
>   to 
>   the Religious Objections. 
>   . 
>   .* 
>   was 
>   written 
>   to 
>   forestall objections which, in 
>   the 
>   event, did 
>   not 
>   arise, 
>   and that 
>   its 
>   publication 
>   has 
>   subsequently 
>   been 
>   mis-interpreted 
>   by 
>   other 
>   commentators  as 
>   evidence 
>   for a 
>   non-existent 
>   opposition. Personal 
>   reservations 
>   about 
>   anaesthesia 
>   upon 
>   religious 
>   grounds 
>   were 
>   certainly  felt,  but  the 
>   lack 
>   of 
>   evidence - either 
>   for  theological  opposition 
>   to 
>   anaesthesia  from 
>   the 
>   institutional 
>   churches 
>   or 
>   of 
>   any 
>   widely 
>   held 
>   (or expressed) 
>   opposition 
>   on 
>   the 
>   part 
>   of 
>   individuals - is 
>   too 
>   significant 
>   to 
>   be 
>   discounted.  It 
>   must 
>   be 
>   concluded 
>   that 
>   there 
>   never 
>   was 
>   any 
>   formal 
>   ‘conflict’ between 
>   religion 
>   and 
>   science 
>   at 
>   this 
>   point, 
>   and that 
>   the 
>   whole 
>   episode 
>   is 
>   no 
>   more 
>   than an 
>   artifact 
>   of 
>   historiography<sup>34</sup>.
>
> ...
>
> <sub>33. 
>   SIMPSON 
>   JY. 
>   *Answer  to 
>   the 
>   Religious  Objections 
>   Advanced  Against 
>   the 
>   Employment  of 
>   Anaesthetic 
>   Agents 
>   in 
>   Midwifery 
>   and 
>   Surgery*. 
>   Edinburgh: 
>   Sutherland 
>   & 
>   Knox, 
>   1847.</sub>
>
> <sub>34. 
>   FARR 
>   AD. 
>   *Medical  Developments 
>   and 
>   Religious 
>   Beliefs. with Special Reference 
>   to 
>   Europe 
>   in 
>   the 18th 
>   and 
>   19th 
>   Centuries*. 
>   Open  University,  Ph.D.thesis, 
>   1977.</sub>
>
> <sub>35. 
>   SIMPSON 
>   JY. 
>   (Letter 
>   to 
>   Dr 
>   Protheroe  Smith 
>   of 
>   London, dated 8th July 
>   1848.)In: 
>   SmithP. 
>   *Scriptural 
>   Authority 
>   for 
>   the 
>   Mitigation 
>   of  the Pains 
>   of 
>   Labour 
>   by 
>   Chloroform 
>   and 
>   Other   Anaesthetic 
>   Agents*. 
>   London: 
>   S. 
>   Highley, 
>   1848: 43-52.</sub>
>
> <sub>36. 
>   NOYES 
>   GR. 
>   Letter to Prof. 
>   W. 
>   Channing, dated 3rd 
>   February 
>   1848. 
>   In: 
>   Channing 
>   W. 
>   *A 
>   Treatise 
>   in 
>   Etherization 
>   in 
>   Childbirth*. 
>   Boston: 
>   Ticknor, 
>   1848: 
>   145.</sub>

<sub>1. A.D. Farr, *Early Opposition to Obstetric Anaesthesia* [in *Anaesthesia*, the Journal of the Association of Anaesthetists of Great Britain and Ireland, Volume 35, Issue 9, pages 896–907, September 1980]</sub>